# Borrower vs coborrower

Tags: car, auto-loan

My daughter asked me to cosign on a car loan.  Somehow I ended up as the borrower and she a the cosigner.  Is that legal?

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is legal. In both situations, both of you are responsible for the car loan, regardless of who is the primary borrower and who is the co-borrower.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But be prepared to pay for that car in full. This might not be the case for you, but we get these questions pretty often, the cosigning friend/family member often gets stuck.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I would add to the other answers here is that you should look into who is on the title. Your liability for the loan isn't affected by whether you are the borrower or the co-borrower, but the legal ownership could be improperly assigned to you if the other documents are mixed up.